# Join a table to a pre-joined field in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I'm trying to join a .csv (X) to a .shp layer (Y), but X and Y don't share an ID field.

Another .csv, Z, has TWO ID fields--one shared with X and one shared with Y.

In any other language, I'd first join Z to Y, then join X to Z`/\`Y--but after I join Z, the fields of Z are unavailable as "target layers" in the join dialog.

Is there any way around this without editing the underlying .shp files?